# vcs_info in zsh when git is not in the default location?

Tags: git, zsh, prompt

I use `vcs_info` in my prompt in zsh to get repo info about my current dir. The problem is git is not installed in its default place (I have it installed in my home dir), and so vcs_info doesn't display any info for the git directories. SVN, which is installed system wide, works. Is there a variable or something I can set so that vcs_info uses git command from my git dir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your `$PATH` to include the location where you installed `git`.